# Pivot columns while retaining original column headers

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I would like to count number of yes and no values by Column and groupby index.

I have this dataframe
:

```
col0  col1 col2
A     yes  no
A     no   no
B     yes  yes
B     yes  no
```

I want this:

```
   col1     col2
   yes  no  yes  no
A  1    1   0    2
B  2    0   1    1
```

I tried with `df.pivot_table(index='my_index', aggfunc='count')`
but i only got

```
   col1     col2

A  2        2
B  2        2
```

Comment: @Wen, I've tried a few pivot solutions, but they don't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Wen Hmm, check that output, it seems different?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep `pd.concat([pd.crosstab(df.col0,[df.col1.astype('category')]),pd.crosstab(df.col0,[df.col2.astype('category')])],axis=1,keys=['col1','col2'])`

Comment: @Wen Ah, it's definitely more complicated than a simple pivot problem... I'll reopen this question, so please post that as the answer ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yep , I think so , we should reopen it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`pd.get_dummies` + `groupby` + `sum`

```
v = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('col0'))

v.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    list(map(tuple, v.columns.str.split('_')))
)
v.sum(level=0)

     col1     col2    
       no yes   no yes
col0                  
A       1   1    2   0
B       0   2    1   1
```

---

**Option 2**
`stack` + `get_dummies` + `unstack`

```
(df.set_index('col0')
   .stack()
   .str.get_dummies()
   .sum(level=[0,1])
   .unstack(-1)
   .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
   .sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
)

     col1     col2    
       no yes   no yes
col0                  
A       1   1    2   0
B       0   2    1   1
```

---

**Option 3**
`crosstab` + `concat` by @Wen

```
i = pd.crosstab(df.col0, df.col1.astype('category'))
j = pd.crosstab(df.col0, df.col2.astype('category'))

pd.concat([i, j], axis=1, keys=['col1','col2'])

     col1     col2    
col1   no yes   no yes
col0                  
A       1   1    2   0
B       0   2    1   1
```

Comment: Man just add it to your answer, without your reminder I almost killing a good question ..`pd.concat([pd.crosstab(df.col0,[df.col1.astype('category')]),pd.crosstab(df.col0,[df.col2.astype('category')])],axis=1,keys=['col1','col2'])`

Comment: @Wen I didn't see your answer, please post again so I can upvote ;)

Comment: If you do not mind man, could you please adding to your answer ? feel embarrassed to post as an answer...:-(

Comment: @Wen It is a good answer, shame you did not post it yourself. I've added it, cheers

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks! It works perfectly! Should I change the title of Question?, Wich is a good tittle for this problem?

Comment: @Ambigus9 You're welcome. As for the title, I fixed it for you.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ How can I get the percentage of yes column value for each column?

Comment: @Ambigus9 Hmm, I think it would be a simple extension of this code, but can you open a new post with expected output? It'll be easier to visualise.